# Database error - WordPress database error Query execution Interrupted

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Apache

Hi there I keep getting the following errors which are stopping my site from loading. Does anyone have solutions as to how I can resolve these errors?

**Error 1**

> [Tue Mar 01 03:54:30.132615 2016] [:error] [pid 10514] [client 185.106.92.252:38561]
>
> WordPress database error Query execution was interrupted for query

```
 SELECT option_value FROM wp_options 
 WHERE
   option_name = 'xmlsf_version' LIMIT 1 made by include('wp-load.php'),
   require_once('wp-config.php'), 
   require_once('wp-settings.php'),
   do_action('init'), 
   call_user_func_array, 
   XMLSitemapFeed->init,
   get_option, 
   QM_DB->query
```

**Error 2**

> [Tue Mar 01 03:54:31.310610 2016] [:error] [pid 10321] [client 185.130.5.104:56506]
>
> WordPress database error Query execution was interrupted for query

```
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options 
WHERE
  option_name = 'ossdl_https' LIMIT 1 made by include('wp-load.php'),
  require_once('wp-config.php'), 
  require_once('wp-settings.php'),
  include_once('/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php'),
  include_once('/plugins/wp-super-cache/ossdl-cdn.php'), 
  get_option,
  QM_DB->query
```

Comment: have you made any changes to it recently, either the webserver or updated wordpress

Comment: Takarii I update wordpress when the latest versions are available but I haven't made a note of when this was. When I restart the server the memory is used up in seconds. There's something wrong with mysql but I'm not pro enough to figure out what it is.